# Passing a variable into excel VBA using C# and then running the VBA script

Tags: c#, excel, vba

Let me start by saying that I have no idea what I am doing... So I have outsourced having a company make a code in C# that is attempting to watch some folders and when a new file appears, it inputs the file path as a string into an excel VBA code. So here is my proplem. Lets say the file path is "D:\testFile" the code below works:

```vb
Sub test5(Path As String)
    MsgBox Path, vbInformation
End Sub
```

It displays a message box displaying D:\testFile, and this code below works:

```vb
Sub test1()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\testFile"
End Sub
```

It opens the file. And of course this also works:

```vb
Sub test2()
    Path = "D:\testFile"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path
End Sub
```

And of course this works:

```vb
Sub test3()
    Path = "D:\testFile"
    X = Path
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=X
End Sub
```

However, this code does not work:

```vb
Sub test4(Path As String)
    X = Path
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=X
End Sub
```

I think it is worth noting that the code below also does not work.

```vb
Sub test6(Path As String)
    MsgBox Path, vbInformation
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\testFile"
End Sub
```

It displays the MsgBox but does not open the testFile... Notice the line that opens the test file does not receive any kind of input from the C#... so if the line with the message box works... so should the open line... So... basically... How do I get test # 4 to work? See test # 4 again below:

```vb
Sub test4(Path As String)
    X = Path
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=X
End Sub
```

My thought is that the string being fed in from the C# program is no good... but that doesn't seem like it would cause test # 6 not to work. Also, the excel vba code was saved in a module. But the C# code was set up with a test excel VBA file that was in a sheet. So I saved these codes in a sheet to duplicate his test file (that is... right click Sheet1 and view code). My understanding is that this is not good practice and the final product needs to have the excel VBA code in a module. (just mentioning it in case it is relevant to why this might not be working) Also, it is worth mentioning that the only thing this outside coder tested was a message box... and of course same as I found... that works.

Comment: Do you have the C# code?  If so please post.

Comment: I do... But... I am not sure where it is exactly or how to open it... there was a lot of stuff in a zipped folder... I opened the zipped folder and clicked setup.exe... that's all I have done. These are the folders: .git, Application Files, ConsoleApp1, example files, and packages. Each of these contain several files and folders. Also, in the top level there are a few files not in a folder. They are the: setup.exe, autorun.inf, FileWatcher.application, FileWatcher.docx, fileWatcher.sln

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple... I just needed to add the ".csv" at the end of the file path. If there is only one file path with that name this isn't an issue but if I have 2 files with the same name and one is a ".csv" and one is a ".txt" then that is where i was having an issue.